# coundn't get bean when running a jar packed from a springboot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I can run my springboot project in IDEA nicely but when packed it to a jar and run with the java command,  just got the java.lang.NullPointerException when getting a bean from spring context.

the first class which just got errors:

```
@Service
public class MdspiImpl extends CThostFtdcMdSpi {
public MdspiImpl(CThostFtdcMdApi mdapi) {
        m_mdapi = mdapi;
        logger.info("MdspiImpl is creating...");
        ***mdr = SpringContextUtil.getBean("marketDataRobot");//this is the error code***
    }
}
```

the second class:

```
@Service
public class MarketDataRobot {
}
```

the SpringContextUtil class:

```
@Component("SpringContextUtil")
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public static <T> T getBean(String name) {
        return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name);
    }
}
```

the gradle file:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'programmingTrading'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.blackHole.programmingTrading'
    }
}
```

the running exception:

```
WARN main[AbstractApplicationContext.java:557 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mdspiImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/E:/workspace/simuPrd/programmingTrading-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/blackHole/programmingTrading/infrastructure/MdspiImpl.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.blackHole.programmingTrading.infrastructure.MdspiImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] 
[com.blackHole.programmingTrading.infrastructure.MdspiImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.blackHole.programmingTrading.SpringContextUtil.getBean(SpringContextUtil.java:35)
    at com.blackHole.programmingTrading.infrastructure.MdspiImpl.<init>(MdspiImpl.java:46)
```

It also stem from another problem: @Autowired annotation doesn't work...
when using like this:

```
@Component
public class Scu{
}
```

in another class:

```
@Autowired
private Scu scu;
logger.info(String.format("MdspiImpl is creating...[%s]", scu.toString()));
```

will get a java.lang.NullPointerException: null

spring-boot configuration like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProgrammingTrading {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProgrammingTrading.class, args);
    }
}
```

that is part of reasons of using SpringContextUtil  to get the bean...
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SpringContextUtil` shouldn't be a accessed statically like you are doing... Since you define it as a `@Component` do the following;

```
@Service
public class MdspiImpl extends CThostFtdcMdSpi {

    @Autowired
    private SpringContextUtil springContextUtil;

    public MdspiImpl(CThostFtdcMdApi mdapi) {
        m_mdapi = mdapi;
        logger.info("MdspiImpl is creating...");
        ***mdr = springContextUtil.getBean("marketDataRobot");
    }
}
```

Due to `SpringContextUtil` not being injected via Spring, but simply accessed statically, the `applicationContext` inside of it is ignored and is null in your case.

Also remove the `static` modifier;

```
@Component
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    // include getter/setter for applicationContext as well

    public <T> T getBean(String name) {
        return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name);
    }
}
```

**edit**

The trouble from the latest example project;

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {
    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;

    public ExampleService() {
        this.logger=logger;
        logger.info("Im working");
    }
}
```

Here the `Logger` will be null, when the `ExampleService` constructor is triggered, since the constructor is called before the injection starts, but you can merge this behaviour if you incorporate the injection through the said constructor as follows;

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    private final Logger logger;

    public ExampleService(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
        logger.info("Im working");
    }
}
```

Works perfectly without any trouble...

Comment: @YiTian is packaging proper? You have `ProgrammingTrading` in the root of the app? Other `@Component`s are under that root package? You shouldn't use something like `SpringContextUtil`, if `@Autowired` fails, that util should also fail. Something must be wrong with injecting...

Comment: I just upload a new project and the problems still exist. here is the link:https://github.com/omobh/errorExample  thanks

Comment: @YiTian the problem was that you were trying to use `@Autowired` but before the `logger` is injected, you are trying to access it via the constructor. That won't work. I put that in my answer. Check it please...

Comment: Why would you create a `Logger` bean? If you log something it will always show up as logged from `org.slf4j.Logger`. The way forward is to use `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger([Clazz.class]);` in each class.

Comment: @TYsewyn it is just an example case, not a real case, OP has trouble with such injection logic. There are other non-logger beans that were not injected, which is the issue here. But I agree having such logger beans is by default an anti-pattern

Answer (score 2):

You should never be accessing beans programmatically like you did with this `SpringContextUtil`, just inject `MarketDataRobot` in the constructor of `MdspiImpl` and you’re good to go (since it’s annotated with `@Service`). The preferred way is to use constructor injection instead of field injection, which will make it easier for you to write unit tests. You can also get rid of `@Autowired` if you have only one constructor.

Comment: This might be useful: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html